# Adjust PictureMarkerSymbol size to distance (ArcGIS 10.2.5 SDK Runtime for .Net)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, layers, markers, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I'm working with ArcGis 10.2.5 Runtime SDK for .Net.

I have created a PictureMarkerSymbol that shows data of an area of interest in miles, and the question is, how can i fit the symbol size to a given distance?

I tried with GeodesicBuffer with point geometry, but instead of resize the symbol, change is applied to each pixel of the image, keeping same size and blurring the source image.

I was thinking on an alternative, maybe use polar calcs to get coordinates, measure distance in pixels between two points and resize image with that information, but this is very inefficient and i can't believe there is any better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically an area of interest would be represented by a Graphic with a Geometry of type Polygon. In this case, you would use the PictureFillSymbol to represent this object with an image (which may be tiled to fill the shape).

Alternatively if you are using a MapPoint geometry and want to represent that with a PictureMarkerSymbol then you could do something like register a handler for the MapView NavigationCompleted event and use the MapView.UnitsPerPixel property to determine what size your symbol should be at that scale then update the Width/Height properties dynamically.

Cheers

Mike